# When is it appropriate to omit the overall intercept from a multilevel model?

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I understand that to run a multilevel model like

$ y_{ij} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{10}x_1{_{ij}} + u_{0j} + e_{ij} $

in lme4 I can use

```
lmer("y ~ 1 + x + (1 | group)", data = data)
```

or get the same result with

```
lmer("y ~ x + (1 | group)", data = data)
```

That is, if I don't state what should be done, lme4 assumes I want the overall intercept. I noticed that I can obtain

$ y_{ij} = \gamma_{10}x_1{_{ij}} + u_{0j} + e_{ij} $

by running

```
lmer("y ~ 0 + x + (1 | group)", data = data)
```

At first I thought that if $\gamma_{00}$ was going to be close to 0 anyway it wouldn't make much difference whether I included it or not, but by analogy with [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7950/9162) it seems like it would potentially bias the other other parameters even if the intercept is statistically non-significant.

I'm aware from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model) that it can sometimes be appropriate to remove the intercept in regular regression, and so assume it can be good idea to also remove the intercept in multilevel modelling if we have some good reason to believe the data-generating process is forced to go through the origin.

But are there any reasons for removing the overall intercept that are specific to multilevel modelling?

Comment: Isn’t the answer same as for regular linear regression https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7948/35989 ?

Comment: Thanks - I'd missed that post. I've edited the OP to take it into account.

Comment: The first answer to the linked post says "The **shortest** answer: **never**", so it doesn't exactly say that "it can sometimes be appropriate". Any reason why you think the above shouldn't apply to multilevel models?

Comment: While the first answer only alludes in a general sense to instances in which it can be appropriate, the second most upvoted answer is quite different in tone, and gives 3 examples. I don't have any huge reason to think that things might be different in multilevel modelling, beyond the fact that many things seem different in MLM.